# Setting the last column in a 3D matrix to the sum of all the other columns using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sum

For the matrix P below, I want to set the last element in each row to the sum across all the other elements of that row. For example:

Original matrix:

```
In [70]: print P
[[[1 2 3 0]
  [4 1 2 0]
  [7 1 2 0]]
 [[7 2 5 0]
  [8 2 4 0]
  [6 3 1 0]]]
```

After summing:

```
In [73]: print P
[[[ 1  2  3  6]
  [ 4  1  2  7]
  [ 7  1  2 10]]
 [[ 7  2  5 14]
  [ 8  2  4 14]
  [ 6  3  1 10]]]
```

I was able to do this by summing P[0] and P[1] separately, i.e.

```
In [71]: P[0,:,3] = numpy.sum( P[0,:,:3], axis=1)
In [72]: P[1,:,3] = numpy.sum( P[1,:,:3], axis=1)
```

However is there a way to do it in a single line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
p[:, :, -1] = p[:, :, :-1].sum(axis=2)
```

If you were to start without the zeroed column, you could:

```
np.concatenate([p, p.sum(axis=2)[:, :, None]], axis=2)
```